# Two way binding in dynamic angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, two-way-binding

So, my goal is to ng-repeat over an array of activities and display a specific directive based off of the activity type.  Right now, I'm just testing the idea out to see if it is viable.  I can display a directive dynamically, but the key is I want to have two way binding between the activities in the main.js and the directive that is displayed.

main.html

```
<div ng-controller="mainCntrl">
  <div>Activity: { <div>isIncluded: {{activities[0].isIncluded}}</div> }</div>
  <dynamic-directive type="{{activities[0].type}}" attributes="instance='activities[0]'"></dynamic-directive>
</div>
```

main.js

```
define(['angularAMD', 'dynamicDirective', 'activity1'],
    function (angularAMD) {
        'use strict';

        var app = angular.module('mainModule', []);

        app.controller('mainCntrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope',
            function ($rootScope, $scope) {
                $scope.activities = [{
                    type: "activity1",
                    isIncluded: true
                }];
            }]);
    });
```

dynamicDirective.js

```
define('dynamicDirectiveModule', ['angularAMD'], function (angularAMD) {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('dynamicDirectiveModule', []);

    app.directive('dynamicDirective', ['$compile',
        function ($compile) {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    type: '@',
                    attributes: '@'
                },
                link: function (scope, element) {
                    var generatedDirective = '<' + scope.type + ' ' + scope.attributes + '></' + scope.type + '>';
                    element.append($compile(generatedDirective)(scope));
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
});
```

activity1.js

```
define('activity1Module', ['angularAMD'], function (angularAMD) {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('activity1Module', []);

    app.controller('activity1Cntrl', ['$scope',
        function ($scope) {
            console.log("$scope.instance: " + $scope.instance);
            $scope.thisInstance = $scope.instance || {};
        }
    ]);

    app.directive('activity1', [
        function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: 'processes/templates/Activity1',
                controller: 'activity1Cntrl',
                scope: {
                    instance: '='
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
});
```

activity1.html

```
<div>
  <div>ISINCLUDED: {{thisInstance.isIncluded}}</div>
  <button ng-model="thisInstance.isIncluded" value="true">Yes</button>
  <button ng-model="thisInstance.isIncluded" value="false">No</button>
</div>
```

With the way it is set up now, the console.log outputs that $scope.instance is undefined.  So, $scope.thisInstance.isIncluded defaults to false.  If, in the main.html, I set `attributes="instance='{{activities[0]}}'"`, $scope.thisInstance.isIncluded correctly is set to true, but I have no two-way binding as instead of activities[0] being passed in as essentially a pointer, it passes the value, { type: "activity1", isIncluded: true }.  How can I get the two-way binding to work?  Is it possible?  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried ng-include? May not that fancy but much simplier

Comment: I did look into it, but from what I could tell, ng-include only compiles the html.  Instead, I need a true directive as, although my example above only has two buttons, I intend on having more functionality like saving the activities that I want to be reusable.

Comment: scope: {
                    type: '=',
                    attributes: '='
                }
Write your scope like that

Comment: @YashKochar, I tried that, but $scope.instance still comes in as undefined in the activity1 directive.

Comment: Try to change the data format of attributes from just string to a JSON Object
`attributes="instance='activities[0]'"` instead do this `attributes="{ key: 'instance', value: activities[0] }"`
And take care of the object in another directive respectively.

Comment: @YashKochar I tried this, but it ends up putting `instance="[object Object]"` which throws a parsing error.  The code in my question correctly puts `instance="activities[0]"` into the tag.  That's how I would want it to look if I skipped the dynamic directive.  `<activity1 instance="activities[0]"></activity1>`.  It would correctly create a two-way binding between activities[0] in the main.js with the instance in the activity1.js.  For some reason, the dynamicDirective.js does not create this connection with the same tag.

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround for this is to utilize ng-switch and bypass dynamicDirective.js.

main.html

```
<div ng-switch="activity.type" ng-repeat="activity in activities">
    <activity1 ng-switch-when="activity1" instance="activity"></activity1>
    <activity2 ng-switch-when="activity2" instance="activity"></activity2>
</div>
```

This is not optimal as it could get ugly fast.  I'm not going to mark this as the answer as it is just a workaround.